# createchildcontrol() - user control, custom control, web control

Tags: user-controls, custom-controls, createchildcontrols

I am new to .Net trying to understand about different controls here. I know, custom control, an extension of existing control. User control, a complicated control constructed in .ascx file and can be used anywhere in the application. I couldn't the concept of createchildcontrol() and need of it. 
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It plays the role in the lifecycle of a page request to ensure all controls generated dynamically/via code are in place for binding postback values and rendering out to the page. Also note from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx):

> When you develop a composite or templated server control, you must
>   override this method.

You can check [this page](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/22673) for the full list of events, in order, on an ASPX request.